# @query annotation doesn't work with hibernate-ogm and mongodb in spring boot

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-ogm

I wrote a **Spring boot,hibernate orm** application using **mysql** database.... **But now I want to switch to mongodb**... I used **Hibernate-ogm** for fulfill my requirement. When  run the application the console shows successfully switch to mongodb using hibernate-ogm... But the query is not working... I import below packages for my repository to hibernate-orm and these imports works fine with mysql... But in hibernate-ogm @query annotation doesn't work...

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
```

This is my model

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class User {

   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String nic;

    private String emp;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String mobile;

    private String email;

    private String status;

    private String agency;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    private String userIDandTime;

    private String recentUpdateBy;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "roleId")})
    private Set<Role> userRoles;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_units",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "unitId")})
    private Set<Unit> userUnits;

    }
```

This is my full repository

```
package lk.tradeportal.repository;

import lk.tradeportal.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

/**
 * Created by Ignotus on 1/28/2017.
 */
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Override
    User save(User user);

    @Override
    User findOne(Long id);

    @Query("select u from User u where u.userName!='super@allSLSI'")
    List<User> findAll();

    @Query("select u from User u where u.agency = :agency and u.firstName !='admin'")
    List<User> findAllStaffUsersByOGA(@Param("agency") String agency);

    @Query("select u from User u where u.nic='N/A' and u.firstName='N/A' and u.email='N/A'")
    List<User> profileNotCompletedUsers();

    @Query("select u from User u where u.agency!='SLSI'")
    List<User> chafindAll();

    @Query("select u from User u where u.userName = :userName")
    User getUserByLoginUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);

    @Query("select u from User u where u.id = :userId")
    User getUserByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);

    @Query("select u.email from User u where u.agency !='SLSI'")
    List<User> getEmails();

    @Query("select a from User a where a.nic = :nic")
    User getAgentByNIC(@Param("nic") String nic);

    @Override
    void delete(Long id);

    @Override
    void delete(User user);
}
```

This is my Service class

```
package lk.tradeportal.services;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import lk.tradeportal.domain.Role;
import lk.tradeportal.domain.User;
import lk.tradeportal.repository.RoleRepository;
import lk.tradeportal.repository.UserRepository;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import lk.tradeportal.domain.Unit;
import lk.tradeportal.repository.UnitRepository;
import lk.tradeportal.security.domain.AuthenticatedUser;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

/**
 * Created by ignotus on 1/31/2017.
 */
@Service
public class UserServices {

    private static final Logger serviceLogger = LogManager.getLogger(UserServices.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UnitRepository unitRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserServices UserService;

    public User getUserFromUserId(Long id) {
        return userRepository.getUserByUserId(id);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User getUserByLoginUserName(String userName) {
        return userRepository.getUserByLoginUserName(userName);
    }

    public List<User> findAllStaffUsersByOGA(String agency) {
        return userRepository.findAllStaffUsersByOGA(agency);
    }

    public List<User> profileNotCompletedUsers() {
        return userRepository.profileNotCompletedUsers();
    }


    public List<User> getChaAllUsers() {
        System.out.println(userRepository.chafindAll());
        return userRepository.chafindAll();
    }

    public List<Role> getAllRoles() {
        return roleRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Role> findTraderRoles() {
        return roleRepository.findTraderRoles();
    }

    public List<Role> findMOIC() {
        return roleRepository.findMOIC();
    }

    public List<Role> SuperADMINRoles() {
        return roleRepository.SuperADMINRoles();
    }

    public List<Unit> getAllUnits() {
        return unitRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void deleteUserById(String id) {
        User user = userRepository.findOne(Long.valueOf(id));
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }

      public User getAgentByNIC(String nic) {
        return userRepository.getAgentByNIC(nic);
    }
}
```

This is my application config.

```
package lk.tradeportal;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Created by ignotus on 1/22/2017.
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "lk.tradeportal")
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource(locations = "classpath:tradeportal-servlet-config.xml")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="lk.tradeportal.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TRADEPORTALStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger slsiLogger = LogManager.getLogger(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        slsiLogger.info("Starting application");
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);
        context = application.run(args);
        application.setRegisterShutdownHook(true);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private static void closeAppContext(){
        context.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TRADEPORTALStarter.class);
    }
}
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="ogm-jpa-tutorial" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- Use Hibernate OGM provider: configuration will be transparent -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

        <class>lk.tradeportal</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />-->
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="trade_portal_db"/>
         </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My dependencies are

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--handle servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<Email Dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>      
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--jasper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web-services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-libs</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.hql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-hql-parser</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.ogm/hibernate-ogm-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.hql</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hql-parser</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**What is the error in @query annotation. How I get I data from my database.. Please help me.**

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Do you see an exception or it doesn't return the expected results?

Comment: It returns not any values via my queries... I think error is in my repositories

Comment: Why do you use a

Comment: Using a persistence.xml file with Spring Boot is outdated. Anyway, try enabling the ‘native=true’ attribute in the @Query annotation.

Comment: Ok sir... But How can I do it... Can you update native query with one of my above repository... I'm new to the hibernate

Comment: mongo db repository not support hql. and basically not support native sql query. that is structured with json data types.